# What is the url to edit other users profile

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I can't figure out though how to edit another users profile.

> *If i'm logged in as an admin I want to be able to edit other users profile.*

What's the url for that ? Can someone please point me to the right direction ?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see anything about what you're looking for....

*Every time I've to working with it, I just use the **User Manager** as it's told in the official documentation...*

**Here is the [specific documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/user_manager.md)**

---

*Maybe should you think to create **your own views** :*

- List of Users
- Edit of one User

And a **Form** mapping your User class.

---

*Here is an extract of how to modify user only with UserManager:*

```
$userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
$user = $userManager->findUserByEmail($email);
$user->setUsername('John');
$userManager->updateUser($user);
```